# Can the evenly symmetry property of the modulus of analytic function imply the analytic funtion must be $cz^k$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm interested in the following problem:

For an analytic function $f$, if $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)|=|f(-z)|=f(\bar{z})|$, then it true that $f(z)$ must be of the form $cz^k$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

I have tried some elementary analytic functions I know, and it appears to me that the only case satisfying the assumptions must be that $f(z)=cz^k$.

So far I cannot prove the claim nor can I give a counterexample. Any ideas or comments would be really appreciated.

Comment: Any odd or even power series (with constant coefficient 0) with real coefficients satisfies these properties.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you very much!